# Cartography set constraint to variable

Tags: ios, swift, cartography

I have no idea how to set constrant.height to constant value:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    layout(view) { view in
        let viewHeight = 67

        view.top == view.superview!.top
        view.left == view.superview!.left
        view.height == viewHeight // Error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Dimension' and 'Int'
        view.width == view.superview!.width
    }

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

This should be simple, put as a Swift newbie atm I don't have any working idea, would welcome any help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably solved this one by yourself, but for anybody else it seems that the ==-operator is not overloaded for Int. So changing the definition of your variable to:

```
let viewHeight: CGFloat = 67
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I've resigned from Cartography as there were troubles with topLayoutGuide, which I couldn't fix with it. So I'm accepting your solution (it sounds valid) but did not (and will not) test it ;).